# php if statement - maximum operations

Tags: php

Is there a limit to the amount of operations that you can put in a php if statement.

I am using it to eliminate results based on the parameters/constraints i.e.

```
if($constraint1 == 0 || $constraint2 >= 5 || .. || ..){
       //do nothing it doesn't fit
} else {   
       // nice one it fit's the criteria 
}
```

Comment: One thing is sure, you will hit a readability issue before a technical one. Try to make he code easy to read and you shouldn't have any "max limit" problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO there is no limit.

The operations inside your if statement are not called "parameters" but "logical operations". Logical operations are another type of operation from "arithmetic operation" (e.g. a + b - c * a).

So there is no limit of how long your logical operation can be. But there is a question whether your code is easy enough to read or not. A long logical operation may lose its readability.

Try to split it into readable pieces.

Comment: so perhaps nesting some if's and switches would be better for readability if there are to be many.

Comment: One doesn't have to nest `if`s one could also use names for stuff, which increases readability. i.e. instead of `if ($a || $b || $c || $d || $e || $f) { ...}` one can use `$some_condition_met = $a || $b || $c; $other_condition_met = $d || $e || $f; if ($some_condition_met || $other_condition_met) { ... }` (note that these are not 100% equal, in the second form `$d` will always be evaluated, but that's fixable when short-cutting is required)