# Asking for 2 isset`s as an Function parameter

Tags: php, post, isset

Hey guys quick Question.

Is thecode below correct?

```
if (isset($_POST['testSendDe']) || isset($_POST["testSendEn"])) {"function"}
```

Is it possible to as for 2 isset`s as an Function Parameter in PHP?

Comment: Yes, you can check for multiple conditions with single `if` statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php if statement - maximum operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708325/php-if-statement-maximum-operations)

Comment: <td >" . $_POST['vorname'] || $_POST["firstName"] . "</td> is this also correct?

Comment: No, that last one from your previous comment, is anything but correct. Reason one would be _operator precedence_, and reason number two that using `||` on what will presumably be string values, if they are set, makes rather little sense to begin with.

Comment: okay okay how can i make that one correct. i have diffrent divs and i either want to post the answers from divNo1 or divNo2, if they are set. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You still need to use `isset` to check if the are set in the first place - once you already tried to access a value, it is too late for that.

Comment: so do i right that line into an if with the isset cheking part as params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`null coalescing operator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) for this to make it one liner like below:

```
<?php

echo "<td>" . (($_POST['vorname'] ?? false) || ($_POST["firstName"] ?? "")) . "</td>";
```

**Update:**

If you wish to print some text of your own than what is present in those keys, you could do the below:

```
<?php

echo "<td>" . (($_POST['vorname'] ?? ($_POST["firstName"] ?? false)) ? "printing because either of them is set" : "printing because none of them is set") . "</td>";
```

Comment: @Jimanuelson Did it work for you? I feel now that your check is a little different. I updated my answer

Comment: Hey im trying your code out right now i will let you know thanks in advance my friend! :)

Comment: @Jimanuelson Glad to assist :)

Comment: hey i ran into an problem while trying the code...

instead of printing the values present in the $_POST functions it returns -> 1. i used the first method you sent me.

Comment: @Jimanuelson Yes, you can try the approach in the update section in my answer, like, `echo "<td>" . (($_POST['vorname'] ?? ($_POST["firstName"] ?? 'none is set'));`

Comment: okay i got it i replaced the strings in the 2nd method with the $_POST params and it worked! :D (i tried to print the $_POST data that was set! i think i explained it bad sorry!